# Getting "TypeError: Failed to fetch" with some url

Tags: reactjs, fetch, recaptcha

I'm facing "**TypeError: Failed to fetch**" errors in my React App.

Depending on the url of the query I run I sometimes encounter the error, although the query does return a valid result when I test it in my browser.

Here are two examples with two sample URL:

```js
(function(){

    var GetRequestResult = function (url) {
        return fetch(url, {
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}})
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => console.log(text))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    };
  
  this.GetRequestResult = GetRequestResult;

})(this);

console.log(GetRequestResult('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1')); // Works
console.log(GetRequestResult('http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA')); // Returns 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why the first one works and not the second ?
2. My final need is to retrieve a response from Google's Recaptcha API (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) using the URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify . I am encountering the error on this url also.
   I guess it's related to CORS (I tried to modify the Headers of my requests, to define https://www.google.com as a proxy, to use different methods to execute the requests ...) but without success. Any idea to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.

I was trying to call the Google Recaptcha API (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify) from my frontend.

Due to Google's CORS policy this only seems possible from the backend side.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getRequest() {
    fetch('https://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA')
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( data => console.log(data.response.docs))
    .catch( e => console.log(e))
}
```

The following code is working in nodejs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code returns the "Failed to fetch" error when I try it (just by calling your getRequest(); function). Where could the difference come from ?